# Script to list all crystal reports in BusinessObjects

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, business-objects-sdk

I've been tasked to generate a list of all **crystal reports** that we have on **SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 3.1**, our organization has more than 2 thousands crystal reports and going through each report manually is not ideal. In **SSRS** the above can be achieved by writing scripts to query the **ReportServer database**, does **BusinessObjects** has the equivalent of the **ReportServer** where I can write scripts to get the report list?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Business Objects has a tool called the Query Builder that allows you to query the server. You can find more information about it here: [BusinessObjects Query Builder - Basics](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-42952)

There are sample queries available (including those for all different types of reports objects) if you scroll down on that page to other posts under the "Query Builder blog series".

Comment: Ryan's idea is helpful.  You may also want to examine the source code and build a script that meets your need's more closely.